# How to delete extra code that shows on homepage? [wordpress]

Tags: wordpress

I suddenly get this extra "?>" piece of code that shows up at the top of my homepage.

https://www.wanderella.co

How can I remove it? Please help :(

Comment: which template did you edited recently? Or do you added some code in functions.php ? It is due to mixing html with php or due to issues in commenting php lines

Comment: you have missed some unended php tag in home template. Check your header.php, page.php (seems your homepage template), or Template you have used for homepage

Comment: You can find all edited template files. May be due to incorrect closing of comments or middle occurrence of `php` close tags cause this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just a close of an php tag, if you had edited something in your theme, your forget an added "?>",, just search for it in the code and delete it